# String wired to Case Structure always goes to Default - LabVIEW

Tags: string, structure, case, default, labview

I am trying to take the readout from an instrument and if the readout matches certain strings (from the instrument programming manual) I want to set an indicator to a specific value, different for each possible string. A case structure seems like the best option, with all the possible readouts as the cases. I did this and added "" as the default case to send out a value for the no-match case. The trouble is that if I wire the readout string to the case structure it always executes the default case no matter what the readout (and yes, before anyone asks, I verified that the readout strings match my cases exactly). To check that the case structure was working I wired a constant to the case structure and it works fine, even when I copy and paste the value from the readout string to the constant. Also, I made sure that case insensitive matching was selected so that's not the issue. Anyone have an idea why this is happening? I can post sample VI's if necessary.

Comment: Update: actually comparison of any form (case, equality, etc.) always fails when I use anything other than constants.. Not very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem. Converted the strings into byte arrays and looked at the ascii values. Apparently one had a new line character at the end even though there was no new line on the indicator. Fixed comparison by trimming white space on strings. Look out for that.

Answer (score 1):

To check exactly what's in your string you can wire it to an indicator, right-click on that indicator and choose '\'Codes Display. This will then show codes such as \n for newline, \00 for ASCII 0, \FF for ASCII 255, etc.